# Toggle variable through a function

Tags: javascript, variables, toggle

this question is pretty straightforward. I want to be able to detect whether a variable is false, and set it to true, commonly known as toggle.

Here is it:

```
var hello = false  

function toggleSt(I, E)
 {
     if ((I == "activate") && (!E))
     {
          E = !E
          alert("activated")
     }
     else if ((I == "disable") && (E))
     {
              E = !E
              alert("disabled")
     }
 }

toggleSt("activate", hello)

alert(hello)
```

I pasted the code on JSFiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/kpDSr/

Hello is still false.

Comment: `E` will **not** be a reference to `hello`, it will only have the same value. Changing `E` will not change `hello`.

Answer (score 1):

Felix is right. Try:

```
var hello = false 

function toggleSt(I)
 {
     if ((I == "activate") && (!hello))
     {
          hello = !hello;
          alert("activated")
     }
     else if ((I == "disable") && (hello))
     {
              hello = !hello
              alert("disabled")
     }
 }

toggleSt("activate");

alert(hello)
```

Comment: But that's hardcoding! Any possible alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You assign hello to the new var E when you call the function. So in the function you have the new parameter E that set to true/false. Call the function without a parameter for hello and use hello as a global variable will work as you expected.

```
var hello = false  

function toggleSt(I)
 {
     if ((I == "activate") && (!hello))
     {
          hello = !hello
          alert("activated")
     }
     else if ((I == "disable") && (hello))
     {
              hello = !hello
              alert("disabled")
     }
 }

toggleSt("activate")

alert(hello)
```